# unable to pull/push to remote repo on github from mac terminal

Tags: git, macos, github, ssh, version-control

I clone existing github repo to my local from mac terminal and I pulled a few times without a problem. I modified some of the code then add . and commit and now I cannot pull or push without getting "Permission denied (publickey)." I have tried using both ssh and https and there is a ton of information on how to resolve this but nothing seems to work for me and it is driving me crazy.

When I enter ssh -vT git@github.com

I get:

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [....ip....] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/macbookpro/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
```

My id_rsa is actually in path:

```
/Users/macbookpro/Documents/pub_key/id_rsa
```

If this is the problem how do I update the path?

Shouldn't I be able to just type git pull since I cloned the repo?

Comment: The problem is that your ssh isn't picking up the right keychain. It has nothing to do with git per se.  Look [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/241417) or [here](http://fplanque.com/dev/mac/secure-ssh-private-keys-on-mac-osx-10-5).

Answer (score 4):

Move the ssh keys to the `~/.ssh` folder

Another option is to create `.ssh/config` file with the following:

```
Host name github.com
   HostName github.com
   IdentityFile /Users/macbookpro/Documents/pub_key/id_rsa 
   User <username>
```

Or simply add the key to ssh-agent:

```
ssh-add /Users/macbookpro/Documents/pub_key/id_rsa
eval $(ssh-agent)
```

Comment: eval should come before ssh-add (in case there is no agent runnnig)

Comment: not mandatory, since its trying to load the keys but from the default location. See the original Question

Comment: I just cd into .ssh and I actually have a file there named id_rsa. How do I create the config file?

Comment: if ssh-add is successful, not need to execute an ssh-agent; if it is not, then ssh-agent must be run first (and btw, it is `eval $(ssh-agent)`). also you have a typo in the header of the .ssh/config file

Comment: Agree. but not all the users know how it work so i prefer to explain it all.

Comment: I entered: ssh-add /Users/macbookpro/Documents/pub_key/id_rsa and got result: Identity added: /Users/macbookpro/Documents/pub_key/id_rsa (/Users/macbookpro/Documents/pub_key/id_rsa)   then I type git pull and I still get Permission denied (publickey).